# Code First Entity Framework - Column returns null becuase EF changed the name to include _ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Entity framework changed the column name in the DB, and isn't giving me it's value.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Settings
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Setting { get; set; }
    public string MoreDetail { get; set; }
    public SettingTypes Type { get; set; }
    public SettingGroups SettingGroup { get; set; }
    public int? MinMembership { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class SettingTypes
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(35)]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}

public class SettingGroups
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(35)]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

In the DB you can see that it changed the name of the two columns:

[image]

When I try to loop through the results, type is null:

[image]

How do I retrieve this value?  I've tried renaming the columns in the class and in the DB but that just breaks more things.  What's the proper way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dangit, I figured it out.  Spent way to much time doing so.

It was as simple as adding "virtual" to the properties:

```
        public virtual SettingTypes Type { get; set; }
        public virtual SettingGroups SettingGroup { get; set; }
```

Now I can address it like:
`setting.Type.TypeName`

Hope this saves someone else some time.